# Как сделать обратную форму с отправкой с сайта html

Tags: html

У меня есть простой html сайт и на этом сайте есть форма

```
<form action="https://formspree.io/FORM_ID" method="POST"> 
   <input type="text" name="name">
   <input type="text" name="text"> 
   <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Я обрабатываю её с помощью сервиса https://formspree.io/, но мне не нравится что при отправке формы пользователь перебрасывается на сайт сервиса formspree.io. Есть простой способ обрабатывать отправку формы на своём сайте?

Comment: Данные формы Вы можете обрабатывать при помощи почти любого ЯП. К примеру `php` или `js`. Всё зависит от того, что Вы используете.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<form action="ms.php" method="POST"> 
   <input type="text" name="name">
   <input type="text" name="text"> 
   <input type="submit">
</form>
```

ms.php:

```
<?php
$subject = "Тема письма";
$text = $_POST['name']."\nТекст: ".$_POST['text'];
$address = "email@email.com"; //Куда слать

mail($address, $subject, $text, 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');

header('location: index.html'); //Куда перебросить после отправки
```